# (Typo3 v11.4.0) Why does importing a recently generated page tree from a working server throw an input error?

Tags: import, typo3-11.x

I'm trying to import my page tree from a different server, yet when i press preview all pages show the error message: "One of the inputs were not an array!"

- Both servers run typo3 v11.4.0
- Changing import options does not help.
- Changing export options does not help either.
- Creating a new,empty root-Homepage with extensions disabled does not help.
- Importing with extensions disabled does not help.
- Ignoring the error message and importing anyway crashes the server and requires a typo3 reinstall.

I'm happy about any suggestions where to look further into this.

[Screenshot of the import screen with Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkHk4.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After reinstalling multiple times, repeating the same steps (using option: force uid) and ignoring the error message it worked.